# Metadata Navigation and column filtering

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, 2016, filter, metadata-navigation

We have a document library with metadata navigation enabled.  Some columns in the library are eligible column types for metadata navigation and others aren't.  The column filtering via the column header drop down does not seem to work when metadata navigation filtering is also applied.  Has anyone else experienced this?  Any viable solutions?

TO reiterate,  metadata navigation works on the columns for which it is enabled but we are unable to subsequently use the column header drop down for column types which are not eligible for metadata navigation filtering.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce your issue. The list column filter cannot work after apply the metadata navigation filter.

As a workaround, we can edit the page and edit the list view web part, then tick "Server Render" under Miscellaneous section as below:

[image]

If you want to show toolbar, you can edit the toolbar type:

[image]

Comment: thanks for the reply.  We tried that approach, but it seems to disable the library toolbar containing the new, upload, etc buttons which isn't a workable solution for our scenario.

Comment: To show the toolbar, you can edit the web part and select "Show Toolbar" under list views section. I edit the reply, you can check the screenshot.

Comment: you are correct that it does re-enable the toolbar - but the library specific text search box is no longer available.  I was including that with my previous description of the toolbar.